# Changing bytes in the file?

Tags: python

I have a request to, `"Encode the file by adding 5 to every byte in the file"`. I tried opening the file as read binary, but all that does is add a b to the beginning of the string- I don't think that is what the expectation of the statement is. I tried looking into pickle, but I don't think that is right either.

What else could this mean? Any ideas as to what possible solutions there are?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? In Python 3, the `bytes` type (which prints out like a string with a `b` prefix) can be indexed or iterated over to get integers. Your issue may be as simple as `output_file.write(bytes(b+5 for b in input_file.read()))`

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't actually add a `b` to the beginning of the string -- `b` is just a marker that python puts on the string when representing it to you so that you know it's a `bytes` type, not `str`.  Bytes are really just numbers (0-255) so you can walk through the byte object and get each value, figure out what number it corresponds to and add 5, etc.

*hint* - this task probably gets easier if you choose to use a `bytearray` to store the bytes.